# python decimal rounding issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
>>> round((611.05/10.0),2)
61.1
>>> round((611.05/10.0),3)
61.105
```

How can I get 61.11 ?

I tried with following but results are same

```
>>> ctx = decimal.getcontext()
>>> ctx.rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
```

Comment: Try `format(611.05 / 10.0, ".40f")` - it's `61.10499999999...`, slightly _less_ than the half you're trying to round up.

Comment: You can't get 61.11, because 61.1049 should never round to 61.11. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating point math https://0.30000000000000004.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `decimal` context is applied to decimal calculations:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP

non_rounded = Decimal("611.05")/Decimal("10.0")
non_rounded.quantize(Decimal(".01"), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

Returns

```
Decimal('61.11')
```

EDIT: using `quantize` instead of `round` [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize)

Comment: This is working great in python3.x. But not in 2.x. It gives same.

Comment: Decimals have their own rounding methods, I've updated the snippet with a working version on my py27 and py36